# Wget Curl - Download entire site and run concordance

Tags: python, bash, curl, wget, julia

This might be a strange question but I'm giving it my best shot.

Summary:
I have a program (written in Bash and Julia) which will outputs the concordance output for a given set of text (in a file) i.e. you pass the file(s) and it'll output the concordance output like (indentation of the bullet#s I'll take care later):

```
a. word1 (1001 times), occurred in sentence {2,5,7,11,12,51,122, 711,881,884,.. etc}
aa. word2 (98 times), occurred in sentence {55,77,79,80,81,110, 121,281,284,.. etc}
..
..
az. wordN (12001 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
aa. wordN1 (55 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
ab. wordN2 (4 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
..
..
az. wordNM (995 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
aba. wordNN (15 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
abb. wordNO (25 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
..
..
abz. wordNP (20 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
aca. wordNQ (220 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
acb. wordNQ (220 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
..
..
acz. wordNQ (2220 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
ada. wordNQ (55 times), occurred in sentence {<listofNumbers_comma_separated>}
..
..
and so on..
```

Each bullet has a unique word (which follows regex to determine whether check, in and check-in are three different words or whether check-in can be treated as 2 words (check and in). A user can tweak the regex defined in a configuration file to get the desired word for a bullet. This is all working.
Similarly, a sentence has various regex which determines whether a sentence ends with a '.' or ';' or '\n' etc. Again, concordance piece is working fine.

**My questions:**

1. I want to use wget / curl to get all the text(only) out of a site (entire data) without going into an infinite loop (a link reading another link and making an infinite loop). Saw http://www.labnol.org/software/wget-command-examples/28750/ and http://xahlee.info/linux/wget_curl_tutorial.html and http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/wget/

I guess something like **wget -m** **-l 7** -t 2 -w 2 http://www.website.com will do (tweak -l # if required) but is there any option which can enhance the performance of retrieving the contents faster?

2. How to find the list of all the websites available in WWW (World Wide Web)? Is it available somewhere where I can run wget in sequence/parallel fashion?

End goal (for fun but actually I'm really curious about it) is to run concordance on every such website file(s) where the site allows you to read data/text in some fashion (combined as my script is parameter driven to run concordance on each file entered or a file containing a list of files which contains text in it) on every site in word wide web. OK, that might scare someone but I think it's not impossible.

So far running my program in reading whole SVN redbook ebook / bible / online novel is working pretty good (2-10 seconds) but now I want to harness it on WWW site contents. I randomly checked some rare words (appendix) and they match with output generated by the concordance script/program.

Has anybody tried this on a minimal scale i.e. running concordance on a company's website only or all site which ends with .in (India) etc.